# Error en WebView Android

Tags: java, android, webview

Estoy intentando hacer una aplicación que muestre una pagina web. El código aparentemente no me da error alguno. Sin embargo al intentar cargar mi sitio web la pantalla se queda en blanco y no muestra el contenido. He intentado con otros sitios web y estos al parecer si los muestra, el problema solo se presenta con mi sitio web. He copiado el enlace tal y como aparece en el navegador, así que dudo que sea un problema de escritura, aun así, les dejo mi código... Espero me puedan ayudar.

Pd. Utilizo el lenguaje Java.

Main Activity.Java:

```
package com.goart.goart;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

//import class for Uploading part start

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;

//import class for Uploading part End

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView web;


public Context context;

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;

// the same for Android 5.0 methods only
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
private String mCameraPhotoPath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myweb);
    web.loadUrl("https://goart.online/");

    WebSettings mywebsettings = web.getSettings();
    mywebsettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.clearSslPreferences();

    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    web.clearSslPreferences();

    //improve webview performance
    web.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    web.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    web.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    web.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mywebsettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mywebsettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    mywebsettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mywebsettings.setSavePassword(true);
    mywebsettings.setSaveFormData(true);
    mywebsettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);


  //enable upload part

    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        // for Lollipop, all in one
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

                // create the file where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                }

                // continue only if the file was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }

            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

            Intent[] intentArray;
            if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            } else {
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }

            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, getString(R.string.image_chooser));
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

            return true;
        }

        // creating image files (Lollipop only)
        private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

            File imageStorageDir = new 
    File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), 
    "DirectoryNameHere");

            if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
            }

            // create an image file name
            imageStorageDir = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" + 
     String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
            return imageStorageDir;
        }

        // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;

            try {
                File imageStorageDir = new 
    File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), 
    "DirectoryNameHere");

                if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                    imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
                }

                File file = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");

                mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file); // save to the private variable

                final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
                // captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");

                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, getString(R.string.image_chooser));
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[]{captureIntent});

                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Camera Exception:" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }

        // openFileChooser for other Android versions
        /* may not work on KitKat due to lack of implementation of openFileChooser() or onShowFileChooser()
           https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220
           however newer versions of KitKat fixed it on some devices */
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
        }

    });
}



// return here when file selected from camera or from SD Card
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    // code for all versions except of Lollipop
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
            if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                return;
            }

            Uri result = null;

            try {
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                    result = null;
                } else {
                    // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                    result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }

    } // end of code for all versions except of Lollipop

    // start of code for Lollipop only
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }

        Uri[] results = null;

        // check that the response is a good one
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null || data.getData() == null) {
                // if there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                }
            } else {
                String dataString = data.getDataString();
                if (dataString != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                }
            }
        }

        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
        mFilePathCallback = null;

    } // end of code for Lollipop only


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(web.canGoBack()){

        web.goBack();
    }
    else {

        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

En el archivo AndroidManifest.xml tengo lo siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.goart.goart">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

SplashScreen.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/fondo"
tools:context=".SplashScreenActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:text="Por GoArt©"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

SplashScreenActivity.Java

```
package com.goart.goart;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, 
            MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }, 3000);
}
}
```

MainActivity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/myweb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Tambien dejo el codigo del strings.xml

```
<resources>
   <string name="app_name">GoArt</string>
   <string name="image_chooser">File Chooser</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: tu codigo debería funcionar, me parece que el problema sería el layout, agrega el layout donde tienes el WebView por favor.

Comment: Ya he editado la pregunta, he añadido 3 códigos mas... *SplashScreen.xml, MainActivity.xml y Strings.xml

Comment: Te muestra algo en el LogCat? @JonasAja

Comment: Ningun error, muestra que todo esta correcto.

Comment: Por favor elimina  las lineas : web.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);   web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);        @JonasAja y comentá si funcionó para agregar una respuesta.

Comment: No, el problema persiste, sigue dando la vista en blanco.

Comment: De hecho cuando hice ese cambio aparecio un error en el Logcat *2020-11-24 19:39:38.109 5687-5879/com.goart.goart E/chromium: [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(959)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202*

Comment: has logrado solucionar el error, tengo el mismo problema

Answer (score -1):

El problema es porque en el dispositivo esta desactualizada o no instalada la aplicación de Android System Webview

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]